# How to use ng-include from code?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive, angularjs-ng-include

I want to use ng-include directive from the code. Something like

```
var html = '<div ng-include="\'myTemplate.html\'"></div>';
$compile(html)($scope);
angular.element(document.getElementById('myDiv')).append(html);
```

but, this one is not working as expected. Can anyone explain how to achieve this properly?

Comment: Did you added the template script `myTemplate.html` inside the ng-app element? Or is `myTemplate.html` the right url where the template can be fetched?

Comment: It is the right url.

Comment: So you can see the request to `//host/path/myTemplate.html` done on the browser console?

Answer (score 0):

If you want include html into your webpage, you should use ng-bing-html instead :

HTML

```
<div id="myDiv" ng-bind-html="template"></div>
```

JS

```
.controller('name', function($scope, $http, $sce, ...) {
    $http.get('myTemplate.html').success(function(template) {
        $scope.template = $sce.trustAsHtml(template);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of your statements.

```
var html = '<div id="dynamicID" ng-include="\'myTemplate.html\'"></div>';
var ngEl = angular.element(document.getElementById('myDiv'));
ngEl.append(html);
$compile(ngEl.find('#dynamicID'))($scope);
```